# How to enable authorize in Swagger.?

Tags: oauth-2.0, swagger, api-platform.com, lexikjwtauthbundle

In my project, the api_platform.yaml file is created in the routes folder, not in the packages folder. I can't make changes to api_platform.yaml.

1. I moved api_platform.yaml file from routes folder to packages folder swagger didn't work.
2. I tried localizing the api_platform.yaml file and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling API Platform [from scratch](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/#using-symfony-cli):

```
symfony new my-new-app
cd my-new-app
composer require api
```